# How to calculate $P(\sum_{i=1}^{m}(A_i+S_i)\le L)$ with $A_i,L\sim\text{exp}(\lambda),S_i\sim\text{exp}(\mu)$ and positive integers $\lambda\neq\mu$?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, integration

Recently I was stumped by the calculation of the probability
$$\mathbb{P} \big(\sum_{i=1}^{m} (A_i + S_i) \le L < \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} (A_i + S_i) \big)$$ 
where $A_i \sim \text{exp}(\lambda), S_i \sim \text{exp}(\mu), L \sim \text{exp}(\lambda)$ are mutually independent, $\lambda \neq \mu$ are two positive integers, and $m$ is an integer parameter.

---

**My attempt:**

I failed at the very start while calculating the density function of $\sum_{i=1}^{m} (A_i + S_i)$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} (A_i + S_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}{A_i} + \sum_{i=1}^{m}{S_i} = \big( A \sim \Gamma(m, \lambda) \big) + \big( S \sim \Gamma(m, \mu) \big)$$
Considering the two Gamma random variable $A$ and $S$, their convolution is:
$$p_{A+S}(a) = p_{A} \ast p_{S} (a) = \int_{0}^{a} f_{A}(a-y) f_{S}(y) dy \\ = \int_{0}^{a} \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda (a-y)} (\lambda (a-y))^{m-1}}{\Gamma(m)} \frac{\mu e^{-\mu y} (\mu y)^{m-1}}{\Gamma(m)} dy \\ = e^{-\lambda a} \frac{\lambda^m \mu^m}{\Gamma(m) \Gamma(m)} \int_{0}^{a} e^{(\lambda - \mu) y} \large((a-y)y \large)^{m-1} dy$$

---

**And my failure:**

I was not able to go any further with the integral. And you can image what a messy calculation we will run into when we are going to take the second step involving $\sum_{i=1}^{m} (A_i + S_i) \le L$.

---

**My questions:**

Generally, my question is how to make the calculation tractable.

Specifically,

> 1. Has the probability been studied in research papers?
>      People interested in its background in "alternating renewal process" are referred to the following part of the post.
> 2. What is the density function of $\big( A \sim \Gamma(m, \lambda) \big) + \big( S \sim \Gamma(m, \mu) \big)$ given that $m$ is an integer and $\lambda \neq \mu$ are positive integers?
>      If there is no nice closed form, can we make some good approximation?
>      Related post: [at Math.SE (without proper answers yet)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803867/51434).
> 3. For the whole calculation, is it feasible to obtain numerical solution using mathematical softwares?
>      Are there any off-the-shelf libraries for this purpose?

---

---

**For people who want to know the background of the probability in "alternating renewal process":**

> **Background:** Consider an alternating renewal process, in which a system can be in one of two states: on or off. Whenever it is off, it takes a time $A_i \sim \text{exp}(\lambda)$  before turning on. Whenever it becomes on, it remains on for a time $S_i \sim \text{exp}(\mu)$. Initially the system is off. A cycle $c_i$ consists of the $i$th off-state and the $i$th on-state. All $A_i$ and $S_i$ are mutually independent and $\lambda \neq \mu$ are two positive integers.
>
> **Problem:** Given a time period $L  \sim \text{exp}(\lambda)$, what is the probability that exactly $m$ cycles occur in $L$?
>   Related post: [at MO: its origin; many thanks to @user137846](https://mathoverflow.net/q/163869/28199).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the left resp. right hand sum $R_m$ resp. $R_{m+1}$. As $L$ is $\exp(\lambda)$  and independent of $(R_m,R_{m+1})$ , taking expection with resp. to $L$ first gives
$$\mathbb{P}(R_m\leq L < R_{m+1})=\mathbb{E}(e^{-\lambda R_m}-e^{-\lambda R_{m+1}})= \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda}\right)^m\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda}\right)$$
where we have used that the individual summands of $R_m$ resp. $R_{m+1}$ have Laplace-transform
$$\mathbf{E}(e^{-p(S_i+A_i)})=\dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda+p}\dfrac{\mu}{\mu+p}$$

Comment: Thanks for your neat answer avoiding the messy calculation of $\Gamma(m, \lambda) + \Gamma(m, \mu)$. Basically it is beyond my current knowledge. Could you please offer me more details or references to the techniques you used such as "Laplace-transform" and "taking expectation w.r.t. $L$"?

Comment: (1) For the first step I've only used Fubini's theorem. (2) The Laplace-transform of a (nonnegative) rv $X$ is just the function $p\mapsto \mathbb{E}e^{-pX}$. (3) You can find both e.g. in W.Feller, An Intro. to Prob. Theory 2, (1970)

Comment: I have borrowed the book by W.Feller from our library. It is hard for me to find where the Fubini theorem is (in the Chinese translation version). The Laplace-transform can be found easily in the table of contents. Are you referring to [Fubini's theorem [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem)? In addition, is your approach general enough to handle with another similar probability: $$\mathbb{P} \big(\sum_{i=1}^{m} S_i + \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} A_i \le
L < \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} S_i + \sum_{i=1}^{m} A_i \big)$$ where the numbers of $S_i$ and $A_i$ differ by one? Thanks.

Comment: 1) Yes, I am referring to Fubini's theorem (as it is formulated in the link you give. It allows (under appropriate conditions) to compute a multiple integral as an iterate integral) (2) if $L$ is independent of $(R_m,R_{m+1})$ and $0\leq R_m \leq R_{m+1}$ the first step above is valid (3) thus you only have to compute $\mathbb{E}e^{-\lambda R_m}$ resp.$\mathbb{E}e^{-\lambda R_{m+1}}$  (4) for your case (independent summands) it's easy: just use the product rule for the expectation of a product independent rvs

Comment: It is not easy for me to follow your idea now. I have to learn the material first before giving some useful feedback. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please give me more hints on the first step of "taking expectation w.r.t $L$", namely
$$\mathbb{P}(R_m\leq L < R_{m+1})=\mathbb{E}(e^{-\lambda R_m}-e^{-\lambda R_{m+1}})$$ Thanks.

Comment: By Fubini's theorem you proceed as follows: (1) in the first step consider the values $0\leq r_m < r_{m+1}$ of $R_m$ resp. $R_{m+1}$ as fixed and integrate with resp. to $L$, you get $\mathbb{P}(r_m\leq L < r_{m+1})=\exp(-\lambda r_m)- \exp(-\lambda r_{m+1})=:f(r_m,r_{m+1})$ (2) in the second step you integrate $f$ with resp. to $(R_m,R_{m+1}$

Comment: I have got it. Thanks a lot. I want to use your idea about this calculation in my working paper. Then how should I cite it if you don't mind?

Comment: In my view there is no need to cite this. If you think it is appropriate just cite this discussion (weblink).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at [summation of independent gamma random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Summation) $\sum_i X_i$, in the hard case where the $X_i$ have different scale parameters. It was studied in:

P. G. Moschopoulos (1985) The distribution of the sum of independent gamma random variables, Annals of the Institute of Statistical Mathematics, 37, 541-544

A. M. Mathai (1982) Storage capacity of a dam with gamma type inputs, Annals of the Institute of Statistical Mathematics, 34, 591-597